# Executing Scripts is different when running under different user than the logged in user

Tags: powershell

I have two different users, my regular user and my admin user.  Both have profiles setup for PowerShell.  I log into my workstation ONLY as my regular user. My issue is that when running PowerShell as my regular user, I can type "menu" at the prompt from any folder and it will run the Menu.ps1 script from the scripts folder.  When I try running PowerShell as my admin user, I get "The Term 'menu' is not a blah blah blah".  The only way I can run it is if I change the the PSDrive named scripts: and dot source execute from there.

The only difference that I can find is that my regular user has access to a windows mapped drive z: (its in the Path environment variable also), while my admin user does not.  I was hoping that I would just need to add scripts:
to the environment variable but that didn't help either.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot add PSDrives to the system PATH variable; the system doesn't know about them. Create the Z: mapping in your admin logon, and ensure that it's also in your PATH, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Jeff Zeitlin.
I added this to my Admin users profile, works perfectly.

```
$ScriptsPath = "\\Server\Share\Scripts"
$ScriptsDrive = "Z:"
$Network = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Network"
$Network.MapNetworkDrive("$($ScriptsDrive)","$($ScriptsPath)")
$strPath=$env:path
if (!($strPath.ToUpper().Contains($ScriptsDrive))) {
    $env:path += ";" + $ScriptsDrive + "\"
}
```